# Difference between AWS amazonei_tensorflow and tensorflow conda environments

Tags: python, aws, anaconda, sagemaker

In AWS SageMaker there are several Conda environments available based on different ML frameworks:

`conda info -e`

[image]

I would like to know the difference between a `tensorflow` and an `amazonei_tensorflow` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `amazonei` environments are for use with the [Amazon Elastic Inference](https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/elastic-inference/) accelerators. You can see this mentioned in the DLAMI README file:

```
for TensorFlow(+Keras2) with Python3 (CUDA 9.0 and Intel MKL-DNN) ______________
____ source activate tensorflow_p36

for Tensorflow(+Amazon Elastic Inference) with Python3 _________________________
____ source activate amazonei_tensorflow_p36
```